# Display actionButton if shiny widget has a choice and another actionButton() is clicked,

Tags: r, shiny

I want a `shiny` app that will display a second `actionButton()` when the `pickerInput()` has at least one option selected and the existing `actionButton()` will be clicked. Otherwise it should be hidden.

```
# Install and load required libraries
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Shiny App with Action Buttons"),
  
  # Sidebar layout
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      pickerInput(
        inputId = "vo",
        label = "Select Outcome variable",
        choices = c("OP1","OP2"),
        selected= NULL,
        multiple = T,
        options = pickerOptions(maxOptions = 1,`none-selected-text` = "Select an Outcome")
      ),
      actionButton("show_button", "Show Second Action Button")
    ),
    
    # Main panel
    mainPanel(
        uiOutput("sb")
      
    )
  )
)

# Define server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  
  # Observe the first action button click to show the second action button
  observeEvent(input$show_button, {
    if (!is.null(input$vo) && length(input$vo) == 1) {
      output$sb<-renderUI({
        actionButton("submit", "Classification", style = "width: 155px; height: 55px; color: #fff; background-color: #0dc5c1; border-color: #0dc5c1; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; border-radius: 10px;")
      })
    }
    else{
      return(NULL)
    }
  })
  
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
 
  output$sb<-renderUI({
    if (input$show_button & !is.null(input$vo) && length(input$vo) == 1) {
      actionButton("submit", "Classification", style = "width: 155px; height: 55px; color: #fff; background-color: #0dc5c1; border-color: #0dc5c1; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; border-radius: 10px;")
    } else return(NULL)
  })
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the accepted answer, if you firstly click the `"Show Second Action Button"` button, and after that you select an option in the picker input, then the second action button will appear. I think you don't want that. With the solution below, this behavior does not occur.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Shiny App with Action Buttons"),
  
  # Sidebar layout
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      pickerInput(
        inputId = "vo",
        label = "Select Outcome variable",
        choices = c("OP1","OP2"),
        selected= NULL,
        multiple = T,
        options = pickerOptions(maxOptions = 1,`none-selected-text` = "Select an Outcome")
      ),
      actionButton(
        "show_button", 
        "Show Second Action Button",
        onclick = "if($('#vo').val().length > 0) {Shiny.setInputValue('showBtn', true);}"
      )
    ),
    
    # Main panel
    mainPanel(
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.showBtn",
        actionButton("submit", "Classification", style = "width: 155px; height: 55px; color: #fff; background-color: #0dc5c1; border-color: #0dc5c1; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; border-radius: 10px;")
      )
      
    )
  )
)

# Define server
server <- function(input, output, session) {}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

There's also a solution using the `renderUI` instead of the conditional panel: it suffices to bind the click event to the `renderUI`:

```r
# Install and load required libraries
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Shiny App with Action Buttons"),
  
  # Sidebar layout
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      pickerInput(
        inputId = "vo",
        label = "Select Outcome variable",
        choices = c("OP1","OP2"),
        selected= NULL,
        multiple = T,
        options = pickerOptions(maxOptions = 1,`none-selected-text` = "Select an Outcome")
      ),
      actionButton(
        "show_button", 
        "Show Second Action Button"
      )
    ),
    
    # Main panel
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("sb")
    )
  )
)

# Define server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$sb <- renderUI({
    if (length(input$vo) == 1) {
      actionButton("submit", "Classification", style = "width: 155px; height: 55px; color: #fff; background-color: #0dc5c1; border-color: #0dc5c1; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; border-radius: 10px;")
    } 
  }) |> bindEvent(input$show_button)
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui, server)
```